# XNA How do I detect if my mouse if hovering over a specific sprite?

Tags: xna

How do I detect if my mouse if hovering over a specific sprite?

For example I'm making a custom button and I want to check if my mouse is hovering over it so I can make animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things:

1. [Get the position of the mouse cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197572.aspx)
2. Get the position and size of your sprite texture (`Texture2d` has a [very handy propery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.bounds.aspx) that does just that)

The second point depends of your implementation but you could have a `Sprite` class that holds a reference to a `Texture2d` and a `Vector2` for the position.

The `Bounds` property of `Texture2` returns a `Rectangle` which has a [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.contains(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) method that does exactly what we need. So from here we can write a very simple function that returns true when a point is located within a given sprite.

```
bool IsPointOverSprite(float x, float y, Sprite sprite)
{
    return (sprite.getTexture().getBounds().Contains(pos.X, pos.Y);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the Bounds property only gives you a width and height in the rectangle, as textures don't have an origin location. getBounds() in this context will be retrieving the Bounds property and combining it with your sprite's location.